# Linux absolute and relative links to files within an svn repository

Tags: svn, symlink, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm running linux and I'm using subversion to handle my files. I have symlinks in my repository, that point to files in the same repository. E.g

An ordinary file
/home/daniel/svn_local_trunk/A/B/MyTextFile.txt

A symlink to the ordinary file
/home/daniel/svn_local_trunk/A/B/C/D/E/MyLink  -> /home/daniel/svn_local_trunk/A/B/MyTextFile.txt

I would now like to checkout this repository to e.g.
/home/daniel/svn_local_trunk2

I then want the following behaviour
/home/daniel/svn_local_trunk2/A/B/C/D/E/MyLink  -> /home/daniel/svn_local_trunk2/A/B/MyTextFile.txt
Not
/home/daniel/svn_local_trunk2/A/B/C/D/E/MyLink  -> /home/daniel/svn_local_trunk/A/B/MyTextFile.txt

Any ideas?

Making relative links seems to be a solution
/home/daniel/svn_local_trunk/A/B/C/D/E/MyLink  -> ../../../MyTextFile.txt
But I have a lot of files and a lot of links and quite a deep file hierarchy, so this syntax is confusing and not easy readable.

Is there another way to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, I chose to use relative links as described above. It solves the main problem. 
The relative links can be created using the command:
“symlinks -cr .”
Use the command:
"realpath"
to view the full path of a relative link.